# Placing one text above another text - html & css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a text above another text line

```
Test
Upgrade
```

My html and css seem alright but it is being positioned like

```
Test Upgrade
```

What is wrong in my code?

```css
.upgrade {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="upgrade">
    <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-user-link">
      <span class="user-name">Upgrade</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="upgrade">
    <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-user-link">
      <span class="user-name">Test</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</li>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh5Dc.png)

Comment: remove display: inline-block; from upgrade

Comment: Your code outputs "**Upgrade Test**" not "**Test Upgrade**"

Comment: Firstly remove the `display: inline-block;`.
Second I think you need different `<li>` for Test and Upgrade. Like `<li>Test</li> <li>Upgrade</li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change display property in upgrade class to block

```
.upgrade {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: look at the image please, the test is far below the upgrade. How can i get it closer to the upgrade?

Comment: set line-height property in css

Answer (score 0):

apparently you've a confusion regarding the display type "inline-block", which will make your text appears in a way you don't want.

The way to obtain the result you want could be "display: block".

Check a list of display options [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)